# Center picture in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need assistance to adapt my code.

Column `E` has 30 images of varying sizes that I want to centre in the cells starting with `E5`.

The code below only centres the images in cell `E5`. How do I adapt it centre all the images in each individual cell?

```
Sub aTest()
   CenterMe ActiveSheet.Shapes(1), Range("E5")    
End Sub

Sub CenterMe(Shp As Shape, OverCells As Range)
    With OverCells
        Shp.Left = .Left + ((.Width - Shp.Width) / 2)
        Shp.Top = .Top + ((.Height - Shp.Height) / 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Column E has 30 images - are there truly 30 images in column E or traversing column E? Also shape will pick up any shape  so is there a more accurate way to target these shapes? E.g. .Type = msoPicture

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub CENTER_SHAPES()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim MyShape As Shape

For Each MyShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If MyShape.Type = msoPicture Then CenterMe MyShape, Range(MyShape.TopLeftCell.Address(False, False))
Next MyShape

Set MyShape = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code will loop every shape (image type) on active worksheet, and it will initiate your sub for centering. Hope it helps!

**UPDATED ANSWER:** Added ScreenUpdating=False because OP said it takes around 7 minutes.

Comment: depending on if OP replies you might consider testing the shape type  e.g. might be .Type = msoPicture

Comment: The code works fine although it takes a considerable amount of time to do depending on the number of images contained in each file. The longest period has been over 7mins (added timer to the code to see how long it actually takes).

Comment: @BaberBeg Please, check updated answer. I addedd ScreenUpdating=false, so it should take less time. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns have incorporated this as well.

Comment: @BaberBeg Does it work better now? If it helped, please, mark the answer as correct :)